# How to use Delphi Dll(with PChar type) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, pinvoke

Here is the Delphi DLL code:

```
library Project2;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

function SimpleConv(const s: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if Ord(S[i]) < 91 then
      Result := Result + S[i];
end;

function MsgEncode(pIn: pchar; InLen: Integer; var pOut: pchar; var OutLen: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  sIn: string;
  sOut: string;
begin
  SetLength(sIn, InLen);
  Move(pIn^, sIn[1], InLen);

  sOut := SimpleConv(sIn);   // Do something

  OutLen := Length(sOut);
  GetMem(pOut, OutLen);
  Move(sOut[1], pOut^, OutLen);
  Result := OutLen > 0;
end;

procedure BlockFree(Buf: pchar); stdcall;
begin
  if assigned(Buf) then
     FreeMem(Buf);
end;

exports
  MsgEncode,
  BlockFree;

begin
end.
```

The Dll function MsgEncode will allocmem to pOut param, and the BlockFree is used to free the memory which alloced by MsgEncode.

My question is: **How can I use this dll in C#? I'm a newbie in C#.**

Comment: What VERSION of Delphi?  (Very important)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to take your question at face value, with a few provisos:

- Whether you are using a Unicode Delphi or not is essential to know for interop code using `PChar` because `PChar` floats between `AnsiChar` and `WideChar` depending on the version of Delphi. I've assumed that you use Unicode Delphi. If not then you'd need to change the string marshalling at the P/Invoke side.
- I've modified your DLL code. I've removed the length parameters and am working on the assumption that that you are only going to let trusted code call this DLL. Untrusted code could produce buffer overruns but you aren't going to let untrusted code run on your machine, are you?
- I've also changed `BlockFree` so that it can receive an untyped pointer. There's no need for it to be types as `PChar`, it's just calling `Free`.

Here's the modified Delphi code:

```
library Project2;

uses
  SysUtils;

{$R *.res}

function SimpleConv(const s: string): string;
begin
  Result := LowerCase(s);
end;

function MsgEncode(pIn: PWideChar; out pOut: PWideChar): LongBool; stdcall;
var
  sOut: string;
  BuffSize: Integer;
begin
  sOut := SimpleConv(pIn);
  BuffSize := SizeOf(Char)*(Length(sOut)+1);//+1 for null-terminator
  GetMem(pOut, BuffSize);
  FillChar(pOut^, BuffSize, 0);
  Result := Length(sOut)>0;
  if Result then
    Move(PChar(sOut)^, pOut^, BuffSize);
end;

procedure BlockFree(p: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  FreeMem(p);//safe to call when p=nil
end;

exports
  MsgEncode,
  BlockFree;

begin
end.
```

And here's the C# code on the other side:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("project2.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool MsgEncode(string pIn, out IntPtr pOut);

        [DllImport("project2.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void BlockFree(IntPtr p);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr pOut;
            string msg;
            if (MsgEncode("Hello from C#", out pOut))
                msg = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pOut);
                BlockFree(pOut);
        }
    }
}
```

This should get you started. Since you are new to C# you are going to need to do quite a bit of reading up on P/Invoke. Enjoy!

Comment: can you safely alloc on the delphi side and free on the other side? Aren't they different heaps?

Comment: @Warren You can't do that and this code doesn't do that! It does GetMem and FreeMem in Delphi, with the same heap.

Comment: What can i do if i use Delphi 6 to do the same functionality. Tried the same step, but value of "msg"  will be  "桔獩椠⁳整瑳". (am using Delphi 6 & Visual studio 2010, .net framework 4.0)

Comment: @bejarun Do you know the difference between `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar`? Between `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString`. Between `PtrToStringAnsi` and `PtrToStringUni`?

Comment: @Heffernan : No, am not familer with PAnsiChar , PWideChar , AnsiString, UnicodeString..etc, am leaning it. please explaing what i have to do the same using delphi 6.

Comment: Not in comments to a different question. Sorry. Start by reading Marco Cantu's Unicode whitepaper.

Comment: @Heffernan, PtrToStringAnsi worked for me. now the text are showing properly. thank you..

Comment: @bejarun Did you change `PWideChar` to `PAnsiChar`?

Answer (score 4):

Note that C# string data is Unicode, so if you proceed with this Delphi code using PChar there will be a hidden conversion from PChar to PWideChar performed in the PInvoke call.  (Conversion meaning allocation of another memory buffer and copying of all the data to the new buffer)  If you intend for this Delphi code to be used with C# and you care about performance, you should change your Delphi code to operate on PWideChar data instead.

There is another reason to use PWideChar instead of PChar: Delphi allocates the OleString type using the Win32 SysAllocString allocator, as per COM requirements.  This means the recipient of the string is capable of deallocating it using the Win32 API.

If you aren't actually processing text in your function but are using PChar as a surrogate for an array of arbitrary byte values, you can get away with that on the unmanaged side of the call but not on the managed side.  If it is byte data, it should be declared as array of byte to avoid charset or char size conversions.

On the C# side of the house, you will need to use PInvoke to call the unmanaged Delphi DLL function. See [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) for details about how to annotate the call in C# to get PInvoke to take care of the buffer allocation automatically.  Find a Win32 API function that passes PChar (or PWideChar) params similar to your function and then search PInvoke.net for the PInvoke declaration to use in managed code.

Comment: @David: Then still using PWideChar allocated through the SysAllocString is important.

Comment: @Jeroen Did you read my P/Invoke answer that avoids SysAllocString?

Comment: @David: wide Delphi: after my time.

Comment: @David: What do you have against SysAllocString?  The code would be a lot simpler, and you wouldn't have to export a deallocator.

Comment: @dthorpe I've nothing against SysAllocString. I'd do it that way myself. I was just trying to answer the question without taking it too far out of the poster's comfort zone.

Comment: @David: yes I did; it feels as a workaround. That's why I like the PWideChar approach more. So if it is not a workaround: explain why it better ;-)

Comment: @Jeroen I don't think it is a better solution to the problem. I just think that the OK has probably no experience of P/Invoke, so changing the signature of the interface even more than I already did would just confuse them. I'm not doing the project for OP, just giving out pointers. Learning new concepts is hard - best to take them one at a time. I'm not feeling the love much today am I?! My highest voted answer was two visible characters (!!) and this P/Invoke graft (I don't even know C# or any .net) just nets 2 up-votes!!

Comment: @Leo I don't know if you are following, but dthorpe's point about exporting a BSTR which can be allocated via SysAllocString will mean you don't need to export the deallocator from your DLL. This really is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Sorry, I did not seen that you export BlockFree function also.

The rule of thumb is: always allocate and free memory in the same module; if you allocate memory in Dll, it should be freed in the same Dll also.

So if you free memory with BlockFree you allocate and free memory in the same module, that is OK.

Note that Delphi string and PChar types are version-dependent - they are ANSI prior Delphi 2009 and UNICODE in Delphi 2009 and after.

Comment: Because I need to realize complex calculations in MsgEncode, the above code is just a simple example.
If allocate memory in the host application, how much to allocate? host app donn't know. 
Yes, the host app can call Msgencode twice, the first to calculate memory size, the second time to actually allocate memory.
But, you know that MsgEncode is very complex and take much time, says from the performance, I don't hope to call it twice.
I hope to allocate and free memory in dll.