# Errors calling delphi .dll from unity3d c#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, unity-game-engine

I got following errors when tried to calling .dll (made from delphi) function from unity3d C# code.

Here is pictures,

[image]

and errors says,

[image]

and .dll codes are,

[image]

So why error occurs and how to solve?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where you write

```
error = GetRequestResult(code);
```

you need to write

```
error = GetRequestResult(out code);
```

which is precisely what the second error message states.

---

Looking at your code, returning a `PChar` from the Delphi DLL the way that you do is not compatible with your P/invokes. The P/invoke marshaller is assuming that your return values were allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc` and will call `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer that you return. That's going to lead to some problems somewhere down the line. I think you'll need to tackle that issue at some point but since it's not the subject of this question, I won't attempt to solve the problem here.

Comment: and I don't understand well about your PChar....comments. So you mean I should not use just 'string' for 'PChar'? Isn't there a easy way to solve this communication problem, like change PChar to another type compatible with c#'s string?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to use WideString on the Delphi side and [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BSTR)] on the C# side. But that doesn't work for return values since Delphi has rather unusual semantics for return values (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop). So I'd convert the string return values into out or ref parameters.

Comment: In fact I already covered this issue in some detail in your previous question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175534/how-to-call-this-delphi-dll-function-from-c

Comment: Hi, Do you have MS messanger ID or Skype ID?