# Invoking Delphi dll from C#

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

Good day!

I have strange problem.
On Delphi side we have:

```
Function Func(str: String; res: double) : double; export; stdcall;
Begin
    Result := res;
End;
```

And on C# side:

```
[DllImport("Project1.dll")]
static extern double Func(string str, double res);
```

It's OK, if i will write like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Func("this is my function", 0.1));
```

Result will be 0.1.

But if I will replace 0.1 with 0 (zero, and 0d, and 0.0 too), I will get SEHException (0x80004005).

Any ideas?

UPD.

Delphi 2007 (no way to change, too many to rebuild ^_^)

VS 2013 (.NET 4.5.1)

OS: Windows 8.1

Platform target x86 (in x64 it does not work at all).

Comment: Delphi version, Windows version (32- or 64-bits)...

Comment: user246408, i have updated post

Comment: [Calling a Delphi DLL from a C# .NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163364/calling-a-delphi-dll-from-a-c-sharp-net-application) and [Calling a Delphi method in a dll from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601423/calling-a-delphi-method-in-a-dll-from-c-sharp)
and [How to call this delphi .dll function from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175534/how-to-call-this-delphi-dll-function-from-c)

Comment: Whatever the reason why your code seems to work OK with `0.1` and fails with `0` (hard to explain without seeing the disassembled code) - the real problem with your code is passing a C# string as a Delphi string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Func(str: String; res: double): double; stdcall;
```

This function can only be called from Delphi because it uses the native Delphi string type. Indeed you can only call it from a Delphi version that has a binary compatible string type.

If you wish to interop with C# you will need to change your signature to use types that are valid for interop. For instance:

```
Function Func(str: PAnsiChar; res: double): double; stdcall;
```

On the C# side this is:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern double Func(string str, double res);
```

As an alternative to using null-terminated character arrays, you could use the COM BSTR type if you preferred. I won't demonstrate that here. There are plenty of examples already available.

Comment: This is becoming a bit of an 'old chestnut'.  Has anyone come up with a C# class that CAN be passed as a Delphi string?  Would it be useful?

Comment: @Hugh easier to use either option in the Q in my view. Interop should be language agnostic.

Comment: Yes, of course - but the OP and others are faced with situations where they cannot change the Delphi .dll

Comment: @hugh The answer there is to recompile with a corrected interface. If that cannot be done then a delphi wrapper ois needed.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
Console.WriteLine(Func("this is my function", Convert.ToDouble(0.0)));
```

Comment: With `Convert.ToDouble(0.0)` **AccessViolationException**: Attempted to read or write protected memory. But it's still all right with `Convert.ToDouble(0.1)`

Comment: how about double dbl_value = 0; Console.WriteLine(Func("this is my function", dbl_value));

Comment: The C# compiler is perfectly capable of passing a double value of 0.0.

Comment: As I understand, Delphi gets params from stack by reference, and 0 is Zero reference. So [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146633.aspx) should help.

Comment: No. The problem is nothing to do with passing the double. You've presented multiple ways to do exactly what is done in the Q. The problem is the other parameter.